# Dropdown from <select> tag doesn't opens for `click()` from devTools

Tags: html, angular, selenium-webdriver, angular-material, devtools

I have to make UI tests for an Angular webApp, and everything was fine until recently the dropDown formed from `` and `` (just regular, nothing special) doesn't respond to click.
The thing is: 
- we use selenium, and preparing it's functionality I like to try everything from devTools. Now, the located  element doesn't open up and shows the values, but no exception or any other problem occurs
- using the real mouse, the dropDown works as expected
- of course selenium fails too to open up the dropDown.
- `` can't be selected directly while the values are not visible

Using an event listener shows that the elemnt do receive the click.
Here is the actual code (again, nothing special):

```html
<form [formGroup]="seasonForm!" style="margin-left: 2rem; margin-right: 2rem">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div style="width: 50%" class="mx-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-select" for="sportId" [AddAsterisk]="!isView">Sport</label>
          <select id="sportId" class="form-control" formControlName="sportId">
            <option *ngFor="let sport of sportOptions" [value]="sport.id">{{ sport.name }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is the event listener (found in SO):

```js
if (document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement);
    });
} else if (document.attachEvent) {    
    document.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log(targetElement);
    });
};
```

ts file is given, I can include if need, so far not found anything related to the problem.
The app uses angular material but I'm almost sure not for the dropDowns.

Can someone help me out?

- Click on other elements (not `<select>` but `<div>` for example) receive and respond as expected.
- Tried on FF, Chrome, Edge, the same everywhere.
- Tried to apply style and visibility, pointerEvents and such too, but nothing made a change.